# Automatização de testes com selenium cucumber e capybara

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Estou começando a aprender a utilizar um meio para automatização de testes em aplicativos web. Porém, me deparei com um problema que não consigo resolver e nem achei em lugar algum (perguntas ou documentação) que explicasse um método que resolveria meu problema.

Bom, em primeiro lugar eu estou usando selenium + cucumber + capybara (em ruby) e basicamente eu gostaria de poder realizar testes no navegador chrome com a emulação mobile e o que me impede disto é que com as minhas configurações dentro de env.rb quando executo o cucumber é aberto uma janela do chrome com a url "data;" e logo em seguida é criada outra janela onde roda meu script normalmente (constatei que isso não acontece apenas com o webdriver do chrome mas com o selenium e com o driver do IE também).

Assim, quando seto as capabilities do chrome para rodar em mobile estas condições apenas se aplicam à primeira janela rodando assim meu script apenas na secundária que permanece normal.

Basicamente minha configuração possui o seguinte aspecto:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium/webdriver'

#Retirando esse register e o default driver eu recebo erro de "rack test requires a rack application"
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.default_driver = :chrome

  mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" => "Google Nexus 5" }
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => { "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation })
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome,  :url => "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps
```

Rodando com este código dentro de env.rb, provavelmente vai duplicar as janelas. Constatei também que sem a linha "`driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome ...`" o browser não duplica, porém não seta as configurações de mobile que eu precisaria. Desde já agradeço.

[image: Print para ajudar na identificação do problema]

Comment: Boa tarde! Tive um problema parecido, ao rodar o script aparecia somente "data" no campo de url do Chrome. Mas no meu caso não rodava o script. Resolvi atualizando o driver do Chrome, para a veresão 2.4.1.

Comment: Tem mais dados?